# Dynamically adding components to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, interface, components, jframe

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add a `Component` inside a `JFrame` after it has been set visible.
Specifically, I'm making a request to a database and based on the length of the result, I want to show a  `JRadioButton` on the screen.
I'm using this code:

```
try {
        Class.forName(Mavenproject1.SQL_DRIVER);
        Connection c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(Mavenproject1.DB, Mavenproject1.ROOT, Mavenproject1.PASSWORD);
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("Select * from calendriers where user = ?");
        ps.setString(1, Login.USER);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            int cal_id = rs.getInt(1);
            ps = c.prepareStatement("Select * from creneaux where calendrier = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, cal_id);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("Hello world");
                radio.setVisible(true);
                Date debut = Date.getDateFromString(rs.getString(2), true);
                Date fin = Date.getDateFromString(rs.getString(3), true);
                Creneau cr = new Creneau(debut, fin);
                creneaux.add(cr);
                System.out.println(cr.toString());
                getContentPane().add(radio);
                getContentPane().revalidate();
                getContentPane().repaint();
            }
            Component[] components = getContentPane().getComponents();
            for (Component component : components) {
                System.out.println(component.getClass().getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error", "error", 1);
    }
```

As an output, I'm having the corresponding `JRadioButton`s are components of the content pane but I'm unable to see it on the screen ,I checked the location using `getLocation()` it said `0,0` , I changed it to `100,100` but still nothing..

Comment: 1) What is the layout manager of the content pane? By default it is a `BorderLayout` and only a single component can be added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`, which is the default if you don't specify a constraint when adding the component. 2) components are visible by default so no need for the setVisible(...) statement. 3) the revalidate() and repaint() should be invoked outside the loop AFTER all components have been added.

Comment: @camickr I'm using a GroupLayout

Comment: And GroupLayout is one of the most complex layout managers. You need to specify multiple constraints to get the components to display properly. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I suggest you use one of the other layout manager to achieve your desired layout. You can also nest panels with different layout managers.

Comment: [mcve] please .. no need for database access to demonstrate a problem with layout :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the UI changes on the event dispatch thread. Assuming the database access is done on a dedicated thread, wrap the UI changes in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, for example:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("Hello world");
    radio.setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().add(radio);
    getContentPane().revalidate();
    getContentPane().repaint();
});
```

Using a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) might be a good idea too.